# Angularjs no module error

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Not sure what's wrong with my code, I got error of `angular.min.js:17 Uncaught Error: No module: MyApp`

http://jsfiddle.net/9g4nxdar/

```
(function() {
  angular.module("MyApp")
    .controller('MyCtrl', myController);

  function myController() {
    var vm = this;

    var item = [{
      "name": "James",
      "age": 20
    }, {
      "name": "John",
      "age": 20
    }]


  }
})();
```

I did declare this in the view
`<div ng-app="MyApp">`

Comment: Add the dependencies array as a second parameter to your module declaration. `angular.module('MyApp', [])`

Comment: @PrateekGupta I see. Thanks, but what's wrong here? http://jsfiddle.net/qnr187m2/

Comment: @SoniaA. As i mentioned in my comment below my answer. AngularJS introduced support for “Controller as” syntax in version 1.1.5. You are using version 1.1.1 in that fiddle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is your just getting a reference to the module `MyApp`. To create the module `MyApp` you need to pass an array as the second parameter like so:

app.js

```
(function(){
    // create the module MyApp
    angular.module('MyApp', []);

})();
```

controller.js

```
(function() {

  // get the reference to MyApp and create the controller
  angular.module("MyApp")
    .controller('MyCtrl', myController);

  function myController() {
    var vm = this;

    var item = [{
      "name": "James",
      "age": 20
    }, {
      "name": "John",
      "age": 20
    }]

  }

})();
```

From the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.module#usage):

`angular.module(name, [requires], [configFn]);`

> requires - If specified then new module is being created. If unspecified then the module is being retrieved for further configuration.

Comment: any idea controller as doesn't work here? http://jsfiddle.net/qnr187m2/

Comment: Yes, AngularJS introduced support for “Controller as” syntax in version 1.1.5. You are using version 1.1.1 in that fiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

Sonia A - In your jsfiddle, just change the "JavaScript Frameworks & Extensions" to "AngularJS 1.4.8" and it starts working correctly.

Below is the fork for the same jsfiddle:
    http://jsfiddle.net/vcvv04hb/

```js
(function() {
  angular.module("MyApp",[])
    .controller('MyCtrl', myController);

  function myController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.items =  [{
      "name": "James",
      "age": 20
    }, {
      "name": "John",
      "age": 20
    }];
  }
})();
```

```html
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl as vm">
    <ul>
      <li ng-click="vm.viewDetail = true" ng-repeat="item in vm.items">{{item.name}}
        <small ng-show="vm.viewDetail">{{vm.item.age}}</small>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```